# In python class, how can I use the variable defined by one function in another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can use the variable defined by function "plus()" in function "other()"? Assume "plus" function cannot return "v_val".

```
class klass(object):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self._func=func
    def plus(self,value):

        v_val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        funcs=[self._func(v) for v in v_val]
        s=0
        for i in funcs:
            s=s+i
        s=s+value
        return s
    def other(self):
        c=0
        for i in v_val:
            c+=i
        return c
```

I am confused since class cannot have global variables.

Comment: Could you add more code and clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use `v_val`, you can make it an instance variable, by prefixing it with `self.`:

```
class klass(object):

    def __init__(self,func):
        self._func=func

    def plus(self,value):

        self.v_val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        funcs=[self._func(v) for v in self.v_val]
        s=0
        for i in funcs:
            s=s+i
        s=s+value
        return s

    def other(self):
        c=0
        for i in self.v_val:
            c+=i
        return c
```

More on `self`:

- [Why do you need “self.” in Python to refer to instance
  variables?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/303082/why-do-you-need-self-in-python-to-refer-to-instance-variables)
- [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)

Also, you might want to read what PEP8 says about naming conventions when it comes to [classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

Comment: Note that nothing guarantees that `plus` is called first, hence the property may not be set.

Comment: @AlexZ It only works *iif* you call `plus` first. It breaks otherwise. Not good.